# Power Series for Original Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

The question:

$y"+x^2y'+2xy=0$

I continue to get the incorrect answer and not sure why. I changed my indices around to make x^n all throughout and that's where the trouble starts.  My answer continues being incorrect

This is my solution, but it is wrong
[image]
Can't find C2n and C(2n+1) after this.  Tried many things but nothing close to the answer.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could show us where you go wrong? To change indices with power series substitution in an ODE, I found being very slow useful. No need to rush.

Comment: I attached picture

Comment: What makes you think it's wrong? Calculations seem correct to me unless I missed something.

Comment: What I had for C(n+2)...the book has C(n+3)=(-Cn)/(n+3)

Comment: And of I continued this, I would not be able to find values when n=0,1,2..

Comment: That's the same! Let $n = m+1$ and check by yourself.

Comment: What do you mean let n=m+1 and why is that done?

Comment: letting $n = m+1$ implies $n+2 = m+3$ and $n-1 = m$ so you get what the book says. $C_{m+3} = \frac{-C_m}{m+3}$